# aws S3 bucket: Internal Server Error 500 on POST file upload from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I receive `<Code>InternalError</Code><Message>We encountered an internal error. Please try again.</Message>` when doing a POST form data upload on to an s3 bucket.

S3 configuration:

```
const attachmentBucket = new Bucket(this, 'caS3Bucket', {
  bucketName: environmentName + '.caattachments',
  cors: [{
    allowedMethods: [HttpMethods.GET, HttpMethods.POST],
    allowedOrigins: ['*'],
    allowedHeaders: ['*'],
    maxAge: 3000
  } as CorsRule]
} as BucketProps);
```

Pre-signing upload url through a lambda:

```
const params = {
  Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET!.split(':')[5],
  Fields: {
    key: payload.path,
    acl: 'public-read'
  },
  Expires: 3600
};

const postData = await new Promise(resolve => {
  s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
    resolve(data);
  });
}) as AWS.S3.PresignedPost;
```

I append all parameters in the postData.fields to the input form with the file. Is there any way to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the form was missing the 'Policy' field. I wish aws errors were more descriptive. Final working form fields looks like this:

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();

formData.append('key', uploadData.fields.key);
formData.append('acl', uploadData.fields.acl);
formData.append('bucket', uploadData.fields.bucket);
formData.append('X-Amz-Algorithm', uploadData.fields.algorithm);
formData.append('X-Amz-Credential', uploadData.fields.credential);
formData.append('X-Amz-Date', uploadData.fields.date);
formData.append('X-Amz-Security-Token', uploadData.fields.token);
formData.append('Policy', uploadData.fields.policy);
formData.append('X-Amz-Signature', uploadData.fields.signature);
formData.append('file', file, file.name);
```